# How to choose the profile for an ontology in OWL 2

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

I know that OWL 2 has three main profiles: EL, QL and RL.

My question is, how to choose the profile when I'm starting to build my ontology.

Is there any easy way to shoose this when we use Protege for building the ontology?

Comment: https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/issues/74 http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/validator/

Comment: "choose"? It's not implemented in Protege because this a) would some background task that restricts the possible modifications of the current ontology w.r.t. the chosen profile or b) some warning after the modification. Both ways do not exist in Protege. The only thing would be to check after each ontology change by yourself with the validator in the second link of StanislavKralin.